# My php script for mailing a form is not working

Tags: php, html, attachment, mime, mail-form

I am trying to set up a form that will send attachments along with the email content, but I have no idea what I am doing.

I am completely new to PHP, and just learned to do the basic mail form work by, basically, trial and error, along with tutorials on the internet. But, when it came to attachments. Now I am completely at loss. And, although the PHP script supposedly runs, and the file is uploaded, all the operation stops all of a sudden. Neither do I get the messages that should show when the scripts finishes running nor do I get an email with the test message and its attachment.

Can anyone help me, or at least walk me through so I can understand what's my error? My HTML and PHP are as follows:

HTML (Form and title)

```
<h3 style="padding-left:290px">Consulta de orçamento</h3>
<form id="form" method="post" action="formulario_orcamento.php" style="padding-left:100px" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <label><input name="Nome" type="text" value="Nome" id="Nome" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Nome'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Nome' ) this.value=''"></label>
        <label><input name="E-mail" type="text" value="E-mail" id="E-mail" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='E-mail'" onFocus="if(this.value =='E-mail' ) this.value=''">
        </label>
        <label><input name="Telefone" type="text" value="Telefone" id="Telefone" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Telefone'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Telefone' ) this.value=''"></label>
        <label>
            <select name="Duvidas" id="Duvidas" style="height:20px; width: 623px">
                <option value="Elaboração de questionários">Elaboração de questionários</option>
                <option value="Amostragem">Amostragem</option>
                <option value="Análise exploratória">Análise exploratória</option>
                <option value="Pesquisas online">Pesquisas online</option>
                <option value="Tabulação">Tabulação</option>
                <option value="Análises específicas">Análises específicas</option>
                <option value="Outras Dúvidas">Outras Dúvidas</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <label><input name="Outras" type="text" value="Outras Dúvidas - Especificar" id="Outras Duvidas" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Outras Dúvidas - Especificar'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Outras Dúvidas - Especificar' ) this.value=''"></label>
        <label><input name="Arquivos" type="file" style="height:25px"></label>
        <label><textarea name="Mensagem" id="Mensagem" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Mensagem'}" onFocus="if(this.value=='Mensagem'){this.value=''}">Mensagem</textarea></label>
        <input type="submit" name="Enviar" id="Enviar" value="Enviar" class="button" style="background:#64d0ff; font-size:14px; color:#fff; display:inline-block; padding:6px 20px 5px 20px; box-shadow:0 1px 1px #fff; width:70px; height:35px" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#1f497d', this.style.color='#fecf06'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#64d0ff', this.style.color='#ffffff'">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$name      = $_POST['Nome'];
$email     = $_POST['E-mail'];
$telephone = $_POST['Telefone'];
$message   = $_POST['Mensagem'];

if ($_POST['Duvidas'] = "Outras Dúvidas") {
    $question == $_POST['Outras'];
} else {
    $question == $_POST['Duvidas'];
}

$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x" . md5(mt_rand()) . "x";
$tmp_name      = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
$ftype         = $_FILES['filename']['type'];
$fname         = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
$fsize         = $_FILES['filename']['size'];
if (file_exists($tmp_name)) {
    if (is_uploaded_file($tmp_name)) {
        $file = fopen($tmp_name, 'rb');
        $data = fread($file, filesize($tmp_name));
        fclose($file);
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
    }

    $to      = "quick.analytics@2frame.com.br";
    $subject = "Consulta de orçamento";
    $header  = "From: danielle.steffen@2frame.com.br" . "\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type: multipart/mixed;\r\n";
    $header .= " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

    $msg = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n";
    "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";
    "Mensagem enviada em " . date("d/m/Y") . ", os dados seguem abaixo:\n\n" . "Nome: $name\n\n" . "E-mail: $email \n\n" . "Telefone: $telephone \n\n" . "Dúvida: $question \n\n";

    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    "Content-Type: {$ftype};\n" . " name=\"{$fname}\"\n";
    //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
    //" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n";
    $data . "\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

    if (isset($_POST['Enviar'])) {
        $res = mail($to, $subject, $msg, $header);
    }
    if ($res) {
        echo 'Mensagem enviada para ' . $to . '';
    } else {
        echo 'Por favor corrija seus erros.';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Avoid the headache. http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

Comment: Please indent your code so that it's easier for us to read.

Comment: And thanks, also, Matthew, for the indenting. I didn't realize I had lost all the indentation once I've copied it to here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have PHP errors that you are not seeing, try adding these lines to the top of your php:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

This code will enable error reporting, which probably will make you see something..

Also, this line:
`if($_POST['Duvidas'] = "Outras Dúvidas")`

is not comparing `$_POST['Duvidas']` with `"Outras Dúvidas"` but is assigning the value `"Outras Dúvidas"` to `$_POST['Duvidas']`, which is always true.. Use `if($_POST['Duvidas'] == "Outras Dúvidas")` instead (note the ==). This might be cause of your problems.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Damien, I've fixed what you've suggested, and I've managed to fix one of the errors that was reported with the script addition you've suggested. Only problem now is that the script reported errors that I have no idea what do they mean. The message that I get is that there are undefined indexes in the line 21-24.

Comment: It means you are using `$arrayVariable['INDEX']` and INDEX does not exist in $arrayVariable. This happens for instance when you use  $_POST['formname']  and the form does not contain a field with `name="formname"`

Comment: Your problem is most likely that you are using `$_FILES['filename']` but there is no file uploaded. $_FILES is empty, so index "filename" does not exist. You can fix this by adding an `if ( !empty($_FILES)) { .. }` around the code that deals with the attachment.

Comment: Thank you again, Damien, that was actually very helpful, I've figured out that the problem is that the file is just not uploading to $_FILES. I'll find out a way to actually make that happen. Thanks for all the help, Damien!