# PHP Mailing script is sending an empty message to my email

Tags: php, html, email-attachments, mail-form

Ironically enough, even though my code is, syntax-wise, completely correct, when I test it, it sends a message to the email addressed to that has nothing content wise, nor attachment wise. Anyone can tip me on what may have gone wrong? Here's the HTML and PHP, any help is appreciated, thanks!

HTML:

```
<h3 style="padding-left:290px">Consulta de orçamento</h3>
<form id="form" method="post" action="formulario_orcamento.php" style="padding-left:100px" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <label><input name="Nome" type="text" value="Nome" id="Nome" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Nome'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Nome' ) this.value=''"></label>
        <label><input name="E-mail" type="text" value="E-mail" id="E-mail" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='E-mail'" onFocus="if(this.value =='E-mail' ) this.value=''"></label>
        <label><input name="Telefone" type="text" value="Telefone" id="Telefone" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Telefone'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Telefone' ) this.value=''"></label>
        <label><select name="Duvidas" id="Duvidas" style="height:20px; width: 623px">
            <option value="Elaboração de questionários">Elaboração de questionários</option>
            <option value="Amostragem">Amostragem</option>
            <option value="Análise exploratória">Análise exploratória</option>
            <option value="Pesquisas online">Pesquisas online</option>
            <option value="Tabulação">Tabulação</option>
            <option value="Análises específicas">Análises específicas</option>
            <option value="Outras Dúvidas">Outras Dúvidas</option>
        </select></label>
        <label><input name="Outras" type="text" value="Outras Dúvidas - Especificar" id="Outras Duvidas" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Outras Dúvidas - Especificar'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Outras Dúvidas - Especificar' ) this.value=''"></label>
        <label><input name="Arquivos" type="file" style="height:25px"></label>
        <label><textarea name="Mensagem" id="Mensagem" onBlur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Mensagem'}" onFocus="if(this.value=='Mensagem'){this.value=''}">Mensagem</textarea></label>
        <input type="submit" name="Enviar" id="Enviar" value="Enviar" class="button" style="background:#64d0ff; font-size:14px; color:#fff; display:inline-block; padding:6px 20px 5px 20px; box-shadow:0 1px 1px #fff; width:70px; height:35px" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#1f497d', this.style.color='#fecf06'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#64d0ff', this.style.color='#ffffff'">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

$name = $_POST['Nome'];
$email = $_POST['E-mail'];
$telephone = $_POST['Telefone'];
$message = $_POST['Mensagem'];
if($_POST['Duvidas'] == "Outras Dúvidas")
{
    $question = $_POST['Outras'];
}
else
{
    $question = $_POST['Duvidas'];
}

if($_FILES['Arquivos']['name'])
{
    if(!$_FILES['Arquivos']['error'])
    {
        $new_file_name = strtolower($_FILES['Arquivos']['tmp_name']);
        $mime_boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x".md5(mt_rand())."x";

        $tmp_name = $_FILES['Arquivos']['tmp_name'];
        $ftype = $_FILES['Arquivos']['type'];
        $fname = $_FILES['Arquivos']['name'];
        $fsize = $_FILES['Arquivos']['size'];
    }
}

if (file_exists($tmp_name))
{
    if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_name))
    {
        $file = fopen($tmp_name,'rb');
        $data = fread($file,filesize($tmp_name));
        fclose($file);
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
    }

    $to      = "quick.analytics@2frame.com.br";
    $subject = "Consulta de orçamento";
    $header = "From: danielle.steffen@2frame.com.br"."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type: multipart/mixed;\r\n";
    $header .= " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\r\n
        Content-Type: {$ftype};\r\n .
        name=\"{$fname}\" \r\n
        Content-Disposition: attachment;\r\n .
        filename=\"{$tmp_name}\" \r\n .
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n
        $data . \r\n ";

    $msg = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n
        Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n .
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n .
        $message . \n\n
        Mensagem enviada em ".date("d/m/Y").", os dados seguem abaixo:\n
        Nome: $name \n
        E-mail: $email \n 
        Telefone: $telephone \n
        Dúvida: $question \n";

    if (isset ( $_POST['Enviar']))
    {
        $res = mail($to,$subject,$msg,$header);
    }
    if($res)
    {
        echo 'Mensagem enviada para '.$to.'';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Por favor corrija seus erros.';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You should use for example `PHPMailer` instead of native function `mail()`.

Comment: Well, it sends an email, alright, but an empty one.

Comment: After `$message` has been added to `$msg`, you add some more text to `$message` but the variable is not used anymore after that. There is also some unused text after you add `$message` to `$msg`. Not sure what you are trying to do there.

Comment: you Americans don't know what irony is :-)

Comment: I actually don't know much what I am doing, RST, this is me learning PHP on the go, basically, while doing an actual thing. And I am Brazilian, Dagon.

Comment: @Sofia you have already asked this question (and gotten an answer) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990822/my-php-script-for-mailing-a-form-is-not-working why ask it again?

Comment: Try echoing $msg and see what it contains

Comment: The problem before was that the thing wasn't even going through, it was aborting on the middle. Now I get a really long message on the window, where I see parts of the actual content that is supposed to go there, along with a long string of random letters and characters

Answer (score 0):

The msg is broken off with the semi-colon at the end of the first line:

```
$msg = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n";
    "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
```

The following lines are therefore invalid syntax. This also happens further down.

Also note that ids cannot contain spaces.

Comment: Okay, so I've fixed the things you've suggested, and now I've received a long email, when using $message as suggested below, with "Content-Disposition: attachment;
.
filename="C:\WINDOWS\Temp\php5E29.tmp"
.
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" and a bunch of random letters right after.

Comment: And, when using $msg in line 72, as originally was, I receive an email  with only "xb360b0fb0d701f96589fd0f97d502387x
.
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-" on it

Answer (score 0):

I believe the line-endings for mime-boundaries (and their content lines) should be '\r\n' rather than '\n'. '\n' can be used for the (plain) text content.

Mime-boundaries should also be unique, I believe, and you appear to have two of the same name.

But I haven't used them so someone may correct me ;)

Comment: That is sort of redundant, I guess, but it didn't make a difference on the resulting message, even after deleting the second mime boundary. And I've added the r\n\, too.

Comment: It should be '\r\n' not 'r\n\'.

Comment: Oops, my bad. I wrote it wrong.

Comment: Nope, it didn't make a difference. (Sorry for the delay, I was waiting on the server to respond, which wasn't.)

Comment: If it is printing the mime details then these details are not formed correctly. Sorry, but the only other advice I can offer is to use print_r($msg) just before the mail() call, and view these details in your browser (view source) so that you can check them.

Comment: Okay, thanks, Andrew. Sorry for bothering you much.

Answer (score -1):

change this Line 72

```
$res = mail($to,$subject,$msg,$header);
```

To this

```
$res = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
```

Comment: Sorry, Alpha Root, but it didn't make a difference, I still get an empty email

Comment: She saved her message in $msg not in $message....